# MPFR: change max/min exponent

Tags: gmp, mpfr

I use MPREAL one-header library as C++11 wrapper for MPREAL library.

I want to work with numbes like `10^−20000000000000=10^(-2*10^13)`

But computation ends with `0`

Running

```
const int max_exp = std::numeric_limits<mpreal>::max_exponent10;
```

which is equals to `min_exponent` with inverted sign, gives `1073741823`

In `mpreal.h` I found following lines

```
// Please note, exponent range is not fixed in MPFR
    static const int min_exponent = MPFR_EMIN_DEFAULT;
    static const int max_exponent = MPFR_EMAX_DEFAULT;
    MPREAL_PERMISSIVE_EXPR static const int min_exponent10 = (int) (MPFR_EMIN_DEFAULT * 0.3010299956639811);
    MPREAL_PERMISSIVE_EXPR static const int max_exponent10 = (int) (MPFR_EMAX_DEFAULT * 0.3010299956639811);
```

The question is: how to change `MPFR_EMAX_DEFAULT and MPFR_EMIN_DEFAULT`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call MPFR functions directly to change the default exponent range:

```
int mpfr_set_emin (mpfr_exp_t exp)
int mpfr_set_emax (mpfr_exp_t exp)
```